# Firestore delete hangs when deleting a large number of documents (e.g. 1000+ documents) at once

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to allow a user to mass delete a bunch of documents. It works fine when there aren't that many documents but when there a ton (e.g. 1000+ documents), it deletes all of the documents and then just hangs. If I close and then reopen the app, I see that all of the documents have been deleted as desired.

My code is:

```
let query = self.collection.whereField("about", isEqualTo: self.about!.uid!).whereField("dataSource", isEqualTo: "appleHealth")
                
query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
  if let err = err {
    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
  } else {
     for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
       document.reference.delete()
     }
  }
}
```

I also tried running it in a background queue but had the same problems. It prints "This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block" but the app just hangs afterwards:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { 
  print("This is run on the background queue")

  let query = self.collection.whereField("about", isEqualTo: self.about!.uid!).whereField("dataSource", isEqualTo: "appleHealth")
                
  query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
      print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
       for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
       document.reference.delete()
       }
    }
  }

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
  }
}
```

Is there a reason why this would hang after mass deleting a bunch of documents but work fine on smaller sets?

Comment: Hello, where is your code running. You might find this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907549/deleting-very-large-collections-in-firestore) usefull

Comment: Better to redesign your firebase db structure so that you can delete the whole node instead of deleting the reference one by one in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are deleting large nodes you may consider using the CLI tools, specifically the 'database:remove'. See the official reference here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en#rtdb-commands

According to Firebase support some time ago, the 'database:remove' command would delete the nodes of your database by dividing them into chunks and thus, preventing your database instance from locking-up.

See related question:
[how can I kill a Firebase transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949197/how-can-i-kill-a-firebase-transaction/54953034#54953034)